# Get day resolution from unix time stamp

Tags: javascript, unix, unix-timestamp

My understanding is that the unix time stamp is resolved to milliseconds

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime()); // 1383507660267
```

so if I wanted second resolution I would do

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); // 1383507729
```

What would I do to get day resolution? (so it would only change every 24 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ...

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
```

That should do the job. Or even simplier:

```
(new Date()).getTime() / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to contend with daylight-savings time shifts, it might be better to normalize the timestamp to reflect some particular time, like (arbitrarily) 12:00 noon:

```
var daystamp = function() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(12);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);
  d.setMilliseconds(0);
  return d.getTime();
}();
```

That'll give you the timestamp at noon on the day you generate it, so if you get it at any time on one particular calendar date it'll always give you the same value. It'll be different only when the date is different, regardless of how many hours in a day.  Thus when the system adds or removes an hour for the time shift, things will still work.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, 3 ways of doing it:

```
var roundedDate1 = function(timestamp) {
    var t = new Date(timestamp);
    t.setHours(0);
    t.setMinutes(0);
    t.setSeconds(0);
    t.setMilliseconds(0);
    return t;
};
var roundedDate2 = function(timestamp) {
    var t = new Date(timestamp);
    return new Date(t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0)
};
var roundedDate3 = function(timestamp) {
    timestamp -= timestamp % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // substract amount of time since midnight
    timestamp += new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; // add the timezone offset
    return new Date(timestamp);
};

var timestamp = 1417628530199;

console.log('1 ' + roundedDate1(timestamp));
console.log('2 ' + roundedDate2(timestamp));
console.log('3 ' + roundedDate3(timestamp));

// output
// 1 Wed Dec 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
// 2 Wed Dec 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
// 3 Tue Dec 02 2014 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/gbf6ac2n/), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sifahe/edit?js,console)

Slightly modified from this source: [Round a timestamp to the nearest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323791/round-a-timestamp-to-the-nearest-date)