# Validating Firebase timestamp data with next midnight epoch time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to validate that the data saved to Firebase has a timestamp value that is greater than today. I know I can retrieve current time using `now()`, but what logic can I use so that I can check against the next midnight time?

Comment: There is no built-in variable for "next midnight". I also can't think of an equation that would calculate that. But you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323791/round-a-timestamp-to-the-nearest-date

Comment: Ofcourse, I can calculate the epoch time to next midnight on the client side. but I won't have server side security check since the security rules are just JSON.

Comment: I didn't say client-side. The security rules executes JavaScript expressions that the Firebase server executes. You could try to fit the calculation in an expression like that.