# check for the same day from epoch time

Tags: javascript, epoch

I am getting list of epoch time values from the server like this

```
response = [[1317888000000, 372.5101, 375, 372.2, 372.52],
[1317888060000, 372.4, 373, 372.01, 372.16],
[1317888120000, 372.16, 372.4, 371.39, 371.62],
[1317888180000, 371.62, 372.16, 371.55, 371.75],
[1317888240000, 371.75, 372.4, 371.57, 372],
[1317888300000, 372, 372.3, 371.8, 372.24],
[1317888360000, 372.22, 372.45, 372.22, 372.3],
[1317888420000, 372.3, 373.25, 372.3, 373.15],
[1317888480000, 373.01, 373.5, 373, 373.24],
[1317888540000, 373.36, 373.88, 373.19, 373.88],
[1317888600000, 373.8, 374.34, 373.75, 374.29],
[1317888660000, 374.29, 374.43, 374, 374.01],
[1317888720000, 374.05, 374.35, 373.76, 374.35],
[1317888780000, 374.41, 375.24, 374.37, 374.9],
[1317888840000, 374.83, 375.73, 374.81, 374.96],
[1317888900000, 374.81, 375.4, 374.81, 375.25],
[1317888960000, 375.2, 375.7, 375.14, 375.19],
[1317889020000, 375.43, 375.43, 374.75, 374.76],
[1317889080000, 374.94, 375.5, 374.81, 375.13],
[1317889140000, 375.12, 375.48, 375, 375.04],
[1317889200000, 375.24, 375.24, 375, 375.08],
[1317889260000, 375.16, 375.16, 374.51, 374.51],
[1317889320000, 374.51, 374.75, 374.2, 374.27]]
```

In this, some of the epoch values are like of the same day, same month and same year also but there is a difference of the time . For example

```
1317888000000 = Thursday, October 6, 2011 8:00:00 AM
1317900000000 = Thursday, October 6, 2011 11:20:00 AM
1317920000000 = Thursday, October 6, 2011 4:53:20 PM
```

My requirement is, if the value I'm getting a value for the new day then in my chart then I will add a new point in the chart but if the new value is of the same day but different time then I will update the value of the same day with new value and new time.

Something like

```
var last = this.chart.series[0].lastValue;
if(//last is of same day but different time){
   //update the last value
} else {
   //add the new value
}
```

So is there any way to check whether the epoch time belongs to the same day or not. I tried it using the `new Date(1317888000000).getDay()` but it doesn't satisfy the requirement properly because if the upcoming value is of next month with same day. It will update the last instead of adding a new value. What should be the condition I should write in my if loop so that it can check the last value added in the chart and the new value both belongs from the same day or not.

Comment: _"same day"_ in which timezone?

Comment: Just compare `getDay`, `getMonth` and `getFullYear` ?

Comment: @Phil Actually I don't have much idea about the time zones. I am using highcharts  so it directly accepts the epoch time with values. Now my requirement has changed to check for the same day values. What if we convert it into ISO String or locale date. Is there any way?

Comment: @JonasW. I have so many values, Near about 60000+ and keep increasing. Is that a good way to check the same day value. I am asking from the perspective of performance.

Comment: @YashJain filtering a big data array is going to be a drop in the ocean compared to rendering the chart

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to work in your local timezone, you could reduce your array down to a `Map` keyed by the *day* (ie, the start of the day) with whatever the latest set of data is.

For example

```
const latestDataByDay = response.reduce((map, val) => {
  let day = new Date(val[0])
  day.setHours(0);
  day.setMinutes(0);
  day.setSeconds(0);
  day.setMilliseconds(0);
  return map.set(day.getTime(), val)
}, new Map())
```

Then you can get an array of values from

```
Array.from(latestDataByDay.values())
```

---

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27323864/283366) for how to round a date down to the start of the day

Comment: I tried it, it is giving me an array of different days. My question was how to check whether the last value that I am getting from the chart is of the same day as of the new value from the server which I am comparing. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @YashJain that could be clearer in your question but you can use the same logic to drop a timestamp down to the start of the day for comparison with another timestamp

Comment: I will elaborate it. As I start receiving the values, first I will check whether the chart is empty or not in terms of values. It must be empty in the starting. So add the first value. Now as the next value came, get the last value (epoch time) from the time and check whether both belongs from the same day or not. If same, update the chart other wise add a new value in the chart

Comment: Sorry for that msunderstanding. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Epoch timestamps are specified in milliseconds since the epoch. Therefore, to get days since the epoch, you just have to divide:

`daysSinceEpoch = timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Since there are 1000 ms in a second, 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, and 24 hours in a day.

Then, you can round this number down using `Math.floor()`, so that all timestamps that are on the same day in UTC time will give the same value, and compare.

Comment: It's a totally naive assumption to make that a day is exactly 86400000ms long

Comment: @Phil How is that naive? Can you find any proof that the epoch time system accounts for the fact that the earth may not actually complete its rotations in exactly 86400000ms?

Comment: My apologies, a correction would be to say that it's naive to assume all days between two dates are exactly 86400000ms long