# Highchart group chart points with same date

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timestamp, linechart

I have a chart with two yAxis. And I want both to be grouped by date. But in my chart the last value of both series are ending up in differnt xAxis line. I assume this is because of the time differences. I need to group these points based on the date so that the last points of both series will align in the same line of xAxis. This is my javascript code.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                  text: 'y axis 1',
                },
                opposite: false,
                showEmpty: false,
              },
              {
                title: {
                  text: 'y axis 2',
                },
                opposite: true,
                showEmpty: false,
              }, 
            ],
            series: [{
              yAxis: 0,
              data: series1,
            },
            {
                yAxis: 1,
                data: series2,
              },
            ],  
          });
```

[And this is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/roczau72/). Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your data and round timestamps to the nearest date:

```
function roundDate(timeStamp) {
    timeStamp -= timeStamp % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //subtract amount of time since midnight
    return new Date(timeStamp).getTime();
}

function loopThroughData(data) {
    data.forEach(function(el) {
        el[0] = roundDate(el[0])
    });
}

loopThroughData(series1);
loopThroughData(series2);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zhbt4gmw/

**Useful thread:** [Round a timestamp to the nearest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323791/round-a-timestamp-to-the-nearest-date/27323864)