# Javascript round date to nearest full date

Tags: javascript, date

I have dates in different formats like these:

```
2022-03-13T23:00:00.000Z
1647817200000
```

I want to round the date to the nearest date basically

`2022-03-13T23:00:00.000Z` should be `2022-03-14T00:00:00.000Z`

and something like `2022-03-14T01:00:00.000Z` should be `2022-03-14T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a timestamp to the nearest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323791/round-a-timestamp-to-the-nearest-date)

Comment: @pilchard no that does not work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule for rounding is `Math.round(N/x)*x` where `N` is a number you want to round and `x` is what you want to round to.

As `Date.valueOf()` returns a number of milliseconds you can simply round that to the number of milliseconds in a day.

```js
const OneDay = 86400000
const roundToNearestDay = d => new Date((Math.round(d.valueOf()/OneDay)*OneDay));

const morning = new Date("2022-03-13T11:00:00.000Z");
const evening = new Date("2022-03-13T23:00:00.000Z")

console.log(roundToNearestDay(morning))
console.log(roundToNearestDay(evening))
```

Comment: Worth noting that for Dates, this is only reliable where everything is UTC, which is not obvious from the answer.

Comment: Use Math.trunc() to drop the time component instead of rounding it to the nearest day.

Answer (score -1):

Having parsed the value to a Date, you can then just test if the hours are < 12, set to the time to 0:00:00 and if >=12, set to 24:00:00 (i.e. 0:00:00 the next day).

The following rounds the UTC day as that's what the OP infers:

```js
function roundUTCDay(d) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate() + (d.getUTCHours() < 12 ? 0 : 1)));
}

// Examples
['2022-03-13T11:59:59.999Z', // round down
 '2022-03-13T12:00:00.000Z', // round up
 '2022-03-13T23:00:00.000Z', // round up
 1647817200000               // round up
].forEach(d => {
  d = new Date(d);
  console.log(d.toISOString() + '\n' +
              roundUTCDay(d).toISOString())
 });
```

This can be done in a UTC or local context, perhaps passing a "use UTC" parameter that defaults to true:

```js
function roundToDay(date = new Date(), useUTC = true) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  let x = useUTC? 'UTC' : '';
  d[`set${x}Hours`](d[`get${x}Hours`]() < 12? 0 : 24,
   0,0,0);
  return d;
}

// Examples
['2022-03-13T11:59:59.999Z',
 '2022-03-13T12:00:00.000Z',
 '2022-03-13T23:00:00.000Z',
 1647817200000
].forEach(d => {
  d = new Date(d);
  console.log( 
  `Round local:\n${d.toString()}\n${roundToDay(new Date(d), false).toString()}` +
  `\nRound UTC:\n${d.toISOString()}\n${roundToDay(new Date(d)).toISOString()}`
);
});
```

The above relies on parsing the value to a date first. The built–in parser is only used because the input timestamps are supported by ECMA-262.